# Strange behaviour of HtmlWindow.Eval

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I am trying to open the out look from a Silverlight application.I use following code to open the outlook

```
            if (parameter.Equals("toEmail"))
            {
                mailString = "mailto:" + emailList + "";
            }
            else if (parameter.Equals("ccEmail"))
            {
                mailString = "mailto:?cc=" + emailList + "";
            }
            else if (parameter.Equals("cccEmail"))
            {
                mailString = "mailto:?bcc=" + emailList + "";
            }

            if (Subject != null && Subject.Length > 0)
            {
                mailString += "&subject=" + Subject + "";
            }

            if (MessageBody != null && MessageBody.Length > 0)
            {
                mailString += "&body=" + MessageBody+ "";
            }

            var cmd = String.Format("location.href='" + mailString + "';");
            HtmlPage.Window.Eval(cmd);
```

mailString is constructed in run time and passed to the System.Windows.Browser.HtmlWindow.Eval() method.It works fine for simple strings

for an example

**location.href='mailto:thabo@yahoo.com;&subject=TestSubject&body=*****************************************************************';**

works fine.

But the string

**location.href='mailto:thabo@yahoo.com;&subject=TestSubject&body=*****************************************************************
NextLine: Test';**

throws an exception. Actually i add a new line to format the message body in above string .I can see that no matter whatever the content of the string  but the new line or line break creates an Exception.

Following is the Exception

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Eval failed.
   at System.Windows.Browser.HtmlWindow.Eval(String code)
   at MyApp.Client.ViewModels.ModuleSendNotifications.Commands.SendEmailCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMenuItem.ExecuteCommand()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMenuItem.OnClickImpl()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMenuItem.OnClick()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMenuItem.ClickItem()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMenuItem.HandleMouseUp()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMenuItem.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)}
```

I tried with the `</br>` tag at the end of each lines.but no luck.It again throws same exception

Any one know how to Fix this?

Comment: have you tried this for new line? --> `\n`

Comment: Could you provide a full minimal working example?

Comment: @WhiteHat Yes .But same issue

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I edited the question.Actually i am adding some parameter from User input.

Comment: Have you tried putting in `%0A` instead of a newline?

Comment: Have you tried `&NextLine: Test`